# PayPal Here List of supported countries

Tags: paypal, paypal-here

I want to integrate PayPal Here in an application I am developing (support card present transactions into my app). Where can I find a list of supported countries ? I am interested if Romania is among them.

Thank you all

Comment: Well ... in the documentation ... did you try there?

Comment: yes I tried. Doesn't have a list or I can't see it have link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of supported countries about Paypal products:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/howto_product_matrix/

In the main [page of documentation of PayPal Here SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/), there's a line that says

> The PayPal Here SDK currently supports US, UK, and AU-based PayPal
>   merchant accounts that have enabled the PayPal Here product.